# In React. How to check each child's, in children array, type at runtime with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, children, runtime-type

I would like to know if there is a way to check types in runtime with TypeScript in this scenario. ***The scenario is just for illustrative purposes.***

```
const SomeReactComponent = ({ children, inverseOrientation }) => {
    const header = findByType('ComponentHeader', children);
    const content = findBytype('ComponentContent', children);
    const footer = findByType('ComponentFooter, children);

    if(inverseOrientation) return <div> {[footer,content,header]} </div>;
    return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused when I read "check types in runtime with TypeScript". There is no typescript in runtime.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense for the reason mentioned above. You may want to use a validator. Or not. It'a unclear what's the case

Comment: The case is something similar to the above, in a collection that supports more than one type. Be able to ask for a specific type to take some decision. But, from the first comment, I realize it makes no sense because after the code is compiled, any trace of TypeScript disappears. Thanks for your comments!